# Sending email by using git-send-email

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel, git-branch, git-send-email

I am supposed to be using git-send-email command to send out patches to the community. I am not sure how to use it properly. I have to send around 5 patches to the linux-wireless mail forum. Do I need to commit the code via git first  and then send out a mail using git-send-email? I am also supposed to send a cover letter along with this. Not sure of what the cover-letter means and how to do it. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Have you read the documentation at [wireless.kernel.org](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/Documentation/git-guide)?

Comment: Take a look at this [doc](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/12/git-tip-of-week-patches-by-email.html) I sure it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Finish your branch
2. Use `git format-patch`: for example:

   ```
       git format-patch --cover-letter --output-directory patches \
           --thread=shallow main..branch-name
   ```

   - You get a cover letter; you get a directory instead of a mess of
     files in your current directory; “shallow” threading seems to be
     generally recommended
3. Use `git send-email patches`

   - But—and here’s the difficult part—you have to have set up your Git
     to be able to send email in some way. This is the part that takes
     97% of the time.